# Mustache for PHP - Methods in value object not called correctly

Tags: php, mustache

I've been trying to define a method on a object to use as values for a Mustache template, but the Mustache template does not call it correctly.  So I must be doing something wrong.

This is an example:

```
<?php    
require './vendor/mustache/mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php';
Mustache_Autoloader::register();

$t = new TplValues();
$t->planet = 'Earth';

$m = new Mustache_Engine();

echo $m->render('Hello, {{# caps}}{{planet}}{{/ caps}}!', $t);

class TplValues {
    public function caps($text) {
        return strtoupper($text);
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for TplValues::caps(), called in /home/user/test/vendor/mustache/mustache/src/Mustache/Context.php on line 138 and defined in /home/user/test/test.php on line 14
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text in /home/user/test/test.php on line 15
Hello, !
```

I've also tried using a helper in the constructor:

```
<?php
require './vendor/mustache/mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php';
Mustache_Autoloader::register();

$t = new stdClass();
$t->planet = 'Earth';

$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'helpers' => array(
        'caps' => function($text) {return strtoupper($text);}
    )
));

echo $m->render('Hello, {{# caps}}{{planet}}{{/ caps}}! ({{planet}})', $t);
```

This doesn't trigger an notices, but the output is:

```
Hello, !
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. You're missing something :)

In Mustache, both a function and a property are treated as a value. These are functionally equivalent:

```
class SomeView {
    public $title = 'foo';
}

class AnotherView {
    function title() {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

In order for a section to be treated as a "higher order section" or "lambda section", the *value* of the section must be callable. Meaning, you need to return something callable from your `caps` method. Your first example would look something like this:

```
class TplValues {
    public function caps() {
        return function($text) {
            return strtoupper($text);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when Mustache calls `$t->caps()`, it will return a Closure, which is passed the contents of the section.

But that's not all :)

Per the spec, the *unrendered* template is passed to a higher order (lambda) section, then the return value is rendered. So your template starts as:

```
Hello, {{# caps }}{{ planet }}{{/ caps }}!
```

When your `caps` anonymous function is called, it is passed:

```
{{ planet }}
```

Which it converts to upper case:

```
{{ PLANET }}
```

... which is definitely not what you intended. Instead, you should use this Closure:

```
function($text, $m) {
    return strtoupper($m->render($text));
}
```

... because now Mustache will render `$text` first to resolve your `{{ planet }}` variable, which you can then upcase and return.

Comment: Thank you sooo much.  I would never have figured that out and never saw anything like this when researching the problem.  Do you have a URL for where this is documented?  I read through the Mustache PHP Wiki, but perhaps I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: The section on variable resolution covers part of it — https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Variable-Resolution ... some of it is covered under "Lambdas" — https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags#lambdas ... but it looks like nothing talks about the difference between a method on a view model and a method which returns a lambda, other than mentioning that "the value is callable". That could be clearer :)

Comment: +1, as this explanation is a lot better than the single opaque sentence in the wiki. Even this explanation is still confusing though. All you really needed to say is that the function receives the *unparsed* string including any nested mustache tags; the helper is there to allow you to parse those tags first.

Comment: Spudley: What, specifically, should the wiki say to make this clearer? Feel free to open an issue on GitHub, or to edit the wiki yourself.